# Jquery For Loop with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display a drop down menu of options that are from database (I used ajax to retrieve these). The retrieving of the data using ajax is working but what I'm having trouble is displaying them.

This is my code.

```
<div id='advocacy'>
    <select name='advocacy[]'>
        <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
                echo "<option>".$row['advocacy_name']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>

    <a href="#" id="add">Add</a>
</div>
```

and this is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add").click(function(){
        fetch();
    });

    $("#advocacy").on("click", "#remove", function(){
        $(this).parent("div").remove();
    });
});


function fetch(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "viewAd.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(retval){
            for (var i = 0; i<retval.length; i++){
                addAd = "<div id='advocacy'><select name='advocacy[]'><option>"+retval[i].advocacy_name+"</option></select><a href='#' id='remove'>Remove</a></div>";

                $("#advocacy").append(addAd);
            }

        }
    })
}
```

now my expected output would be a single drop down menu but what I'm getting is a drop down menu for every `retval[i].advocacy_name`. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert the whole SELECT component for each option of the returned array. Try this callback instead:

```
success: function(retval){
        var addAd = "<div id='advocacy'><select name='advocacy[]'>"
        for (var i = 0; i<retval.length; i++){
            addAd +="<option>"+retval[i].advocacy_name+"</option>";
        }
        addAd += "</select><a href='#' id='remove'>Remove</a></div>";    
        $("#advocacy").html(addAd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$("#advocacy").append(addAd);` should be outside the loop, and it should be `replaceWith` instead of `append` since you are overwritting the same element.

Moreover inside the loop you should only add the `option` elements.

```
function fetch(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "viewAd.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(retval){
            var addAd = '';
            for (var i = 0; i<retval.length; i++){
                addAd += "<option>"+retval[i].advocacy_name+"</option>";
            }
            addAdd = '<div id='advocacy'><select name='advocacy[]'>'+ addAd + '</select><a href='#' id='remove'>Remove</a></div>';
            $("#advocacy").replaceWith(addAd);

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an entire `<div>` on every iteration of your loop. Only use the loop to generate `<option>`s:

```
success: function(retval) {
  let options = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < retval.length; i++){
    options += `<option>${retval[i].advocacy_name}</option>`;
  }
  let addAd = `<div id='advocacy'><select name='advocacy[]'>${options}</select><a href='#' id='remove'>Remove</a></div>`;
  $("#advocacy").replaceWith(addAd);
}
```

Or reduce the loop to a line:

```
success: function(retval) {
  let options = retval.map(r => `<option>${r.advocacy_name}</option>`).join('');
  let addAd = `<div id='advocacy'><select name='advocacy[]'>${options}</select><a href='#' id='remove'>Remove</a></div>`;
  $("#advocacy").replaceWith(addAd);
}
```